# Applying location moves object back?

Tags: objects, transforms

I'm not quite sure why this is happening.
Whenever I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and apply the location, it just resets.
[image: animated gif showing the object going back to the orign]

Comment: do you have any constraints, parents, drivers, or anything else acting upon the location of that object?

Answer (score 2):

This is centainly not normal.

I would suggest:

1. Move the object to where you want it
2. Go into Edit Mode
3. Select everything
4. Press shift+ s
5. Click Cursor to Selected
6. Get out of Edit mode
7. Apply Location
8. Go into Edit Mode again
9. Select everything again
10. Press shift+ s
11. Press Selection to Cursor

Make sure to not move the cursor after Step 5

OR:

1. Shift+ s
2. Cursor to Center
3. Shift+ Crtl+ Alt+ c
4. Origin to 3D Cursor

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's the way *Apply Location* works (slightly different from *Apply Rotation & Scale*) - it sets the object location to 0,0,0 - moves it to center.

If you still want the object to stay at the current position and have zero location, you need to set the cursor to center using *Shift-C* and the use the *Set origin to 3D Cursor* option in the *Toolbar*.

**However, there is very few situations, when you would want to Apply Location.**

Answer (score 1):

Use Apply *** to Deltas.

On your case, Location to Deltas

[image]